# Regarding XML Diff & Patch

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldiff

I got the example from MSDN about how to compare two XML with XML Diff and Patch.
[MSDN XML Diff & Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

It is an easy example but I dont get what I expect.

I have the following XMls:

```
<a>
<component>A</component>
<component>4</component>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
<component>A</component>
<component>5</component>
</a>
```

Running the tool code I dont get exaclty the difference. The output which I get is:

```
<a>
<component>A</component>
<component>5</component>
</a>
```

But for my purposes I would like to get just the difference which differs from the original, in this case.

```
<a>
<component>4</component>
</a>
```

Does anyone know how I can adapt the code to my solution.

Thank you very much.

**edit** code used:

- (Here I find out the differences between the files)

  ```
  public void GenerateDiffGram(string originalFile, string finalFile, 
                              XmlWriter diffGramWriter)
  {
      XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder | 
                                   XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces | 
                                   XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
     bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, newFile, false, diffgramWriter);
     diffgramWriter.Close();
  }
  ```
- Patching up the original file to create the new changed file.

  ```
  public void PatchUp(string originalFile, String diffGramFile, String OutputFile)
  {
  XmlDocument sourceDoc = new XmlDocument(new NameTable());
  sourceDoc.Load(originalFile);
  XmlTextReader diffgramReader = new XmlTextReader(diffGramFile);

  xmlpatch.Patch(sourceDoc,diffgramReader);

  XmlTextWriter output = new XmlTextWriter(OutputFile,Encoding.Unicode);
  sourceDoc.Save(output);
  output.Close();
  }
  ```

Comment: So, why don't you post the code that you are using? I don't feel like reading the entire article...

Comment: I edited it, I got the code from msdn link.

Comment: why don't you use LINQ to compare...? If you want to try XML to LINQ refer http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/compare-xml-files-using-csharp-linq/

Comment: I just noticed that the tool you want to use is from the Stone Age (2002). Is it still supported? You should definitely use something like Linq, as @Deepu suggested.